# MSSQL Stored Procedures Laravel 5

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, laravel-5

How to run a stored procedure in `laravel` 5

I use:

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('exec SP_XXXX ?,?',array($a,$b));
```

error message :

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no
>   fields.

stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_XXXX] (@FROMDATE DATETIME, @TODATE DATETIME)
```

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures."

Answer (score 1):

You should not start naming the SP_.